# Efficient way to calculate dot products using Shaders

Tags: python, glsl, shader, vtk, fragment-shader

I am a beginner to GLSL and I am using Python VTK to experiment with shaders. I want to calculate the dot product of two matrices of arbitrary sizes. Is there a clean way to achieve this using Python VTK ? I have looked at the `SetUniformMatrix` function but it can take only 3x3 and 4x4 matrices. I also looked at `MapDataArrayToVertexAttribute` but could not fully understand how to use it efficiently. I need to find dot product of two 2D matrices.

Comment: Since you are using Python, is it okay to use NumPy only for the matrix multiplication part? VTK has a math class as documented [here](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMath.html) but it does not do dot product of matrices. By dot product of matrices do you mean element wise multiplication (result will be another matrix) or a double contraction (gives a scalar)?